# How to add an OnTouchListener over a gridView?

Tags: java, android, gridview, ontouchlistener, swipe-gesture

So I have a layout that is made of `GridView` and I want to add an `OnTouchListener` to handle the event when the user swipes left or right, so I made a class that implements `OnTouchListener` it's called `OnSwipeTouchListener` and it's working really good but the problem is my gridView, the scroll is working fine and everything but when I click on an item it automatically chooses the first item in the row. any idea on how to fix this or another way to detect a left or right swipe and makes the gridview work fine, thanks.

P.S: the gridView works fine when I remove the onTouchListener.

The OnSwipeTouchListner:

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
        if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
            if (distanceX > 0)
                onSwipeRight();
            else
                onSwipeLeft();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

calling it in the main activity:

```
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this){
        public void onSwipeRight() {
        }
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            }
    });
```

Comment: could you post your code

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setOnItemClickListener`

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(

new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {

    }
});
);
```